# What is the equivalent of city, county and state in the Philippines?

Tags: address, field-mapping, here-maps, philippines

I am developing a map application using HERE Maps and wondering if what is the equivalent of the fields **'city'**, **'county'** and **'state'** for the addresses in the **Philippines**?

Currently, I have mapped these fields as follows:

```
city   == municipality
county == province
state  == region
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this wiki page can help make things a little clearer: [Administrative divisions of the Philippines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_the_Philippines).

The page mentions the three terms you used plus an additional one for villages (quote copied from the wiki page provided):

> The Philippines has four main classes of elected administrative divisions, often lumped together as local government units (LGUs). They are, from the highest to the lowest division:
>
> 1. Autonomous regions
> 2. Provinces (lalawigan, probinsiya) and independent cities (lungsod, siyudad/ciudad, dakbayan, lakanbalen)
> 3. Municipalities (bayan, balen, bungto, banwa) and component cities (lungsod, siyudad/ciudad, dakbayan, dakbanwa, lakanbalen)
> 4. Barangays (also known as barrio)